# Persistance Ignorance Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, persistence-ignorance

I have an existing domain layer. I want to develop the persistence layer using Linq to SQL. I am currently using an external map file. I am trying to use lazy loading for my child collections but am unsuccessful. Is there a way to implement lazy loading using Linq to SQL but without using EntitySet or EntityRef.

Comment: You should rephrase your title and content from "ignorance" to "agnostic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee that I'm up to the latest development of LTS, but previously you had to you use EntitySet/EntityRef to get lazy loading.

You're best bet is NHibernate if you want a PI-model.

Answer (score 0):

(Not really answering the question.)

Entity Framework (aka. LINQ to Entities) in .NET 4 includes persistence ignorance support e.g. being able to map to POCO (Plain Old CLR Object<sup>1</sup>). See ["Sneak Preview: Persistence Ignorance and POCO in Entity Framework 4.0 "](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/05/11/sneak-preview-persistence-ignorance-and-poco-in-entity-framework-4-0.aspx).

<sup>1</sup> I.e. Not requiring a base class or attributes.

Comment: For info, LINQ-to-SQL supported this (and both lazy and eager loading) in the initial release ;-p